# Can I somehow wire my generator to my power pole?

Tags: electrical-distribution

I have a power pole that has a 200 amp breaker before it enters my house and a 30 amp (240) breaker for my well. Again, both are outside before the electricity enters my 200 amp house box. Is there a type of transfer switch that will work at the pole with my generator? Any help or ideas are much appreciated. I am obviously not an electrician so keep it simple. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, absolutely. A 200A service rated transfer switch is exactly what you need. Most are outdoor rated so it can be placed right at the pole with the service equipment.

This switch needs to be matched with the generator you buy so it is not something you can just run out and get. Also, the generator must be able to handle the average load of your home since it will start automatically during an outage, so everything that is on at the time will be part of the load when the genset starts.

This is NOT something for a casual DIYer so please contact an electrician for exact details about your specific job.